# Flexbox parent fit text content of children

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to use flexbox to make a column that can scroll as its text content gets longer.
I drew a picture in keynote to make a better explanation.

[when texts are small](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53R0Z.png)

[when texts get big](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKsey.png)

Here is my current code, just every elements in my code is in flexboxes.
I edited my script to include .app .sidebar

```css
.app {
         display: flex;
         height: 100vh;
         flex-direction: row;
}
.sidebar {
         display:flex;
         flex: 1;
}
.cv {
 display: flex;
        flex:5;
 flex-direction: column;
 margin:20px;
 border: 1px solid lightgrey;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-color: white;
 overflow: scroll;
}
.header {
 display: flex;
 flex: 0 0 150px;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 font-size: 20px;
}
.section {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 border: 1px solid lightgrey;
 margin: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
}
.sectionHeader{
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 font-size: 18px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-top: 15px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 flex: 0 0 30px;
 background-color: gray;
 color:white;
 font-weight: 700;
}
.sectionBody{
 display: flex;
 flex: 1;
 padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="cv">
 <div class="header">Header</div>
 <div class="section">
  <div class="sectionHeader">Section Header</div>
  <div class="sectionBody">LONG TEXT</div>
 </div>
 <div class="section">
  <div class="sectionHeader">Section Header</div>
  <div class="sectionBody">LONG TEXT</div>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have not defined height to .cv but using overflow: scroll; Define specific height to .cv class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do 2 things:

- Give the `cv` a `min-height: 0;`  (fix for i.a. Firefox)
- Add `flex-shrink: 0` to the `.section` so it won't collapse when not fit

Stack snippet

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.app {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
}

.cv {
  display: flex;
  flex: 5;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: scroll;
  min-height: 0;                    /*  added  */
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 150px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  flex-shrink: 0;                   /*  added  */
}

.sectionHeader {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  flex: 0 0 30px;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.sectionBody {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
  <div class="cv">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="section">
      <div class="sectionHeader">Section Header</div>
      <div class="sectionBody">LONG TEXT</div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
      <div class="sectionHeader">Section Header</div>
      <div class="sectionBody">LONG TEXT</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```